# Grails addTo* with result of database

Tags: grails, grails-orm, relationship

Why this code not work fine?

```
def classeInstrumento = classeInstrumentoService.getClasseInstrumento("value")

def instrumentoInstance = new Instrumento().addToClasseInstrumento(classeInstrumento)
```

I receive this error message on console:

```
No signature of method: package.Instrumento.addToClasseInstrumento() is applicable for argument types: (package.ClasseInstrumento) values: [package.ClasseInstrumento : 5]
```

And this is the Domains structure

```
class ClasseInstrumento {
    static hasMany = instrumentos: Instrumento
}

class Instrumento {

    ClasseInstrumento idClasseInstrumento

    static hasMany =  [ativoDefs: AtivoDef,
                      futuroDefs: FuturoDef,
                      operacaoDefs: OperacaoDef]

    static belongsTo = [ClasseInstrumento]
}
```

So I expected that it worked, but it didn't :(

Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Instrumento` belongsTo `ClasseInstrumento`.

which means `ClasseInstrumento` is the parent and `Instrumento` is the child of `ClasseInstrumento` (signified by hasMany in `ClasseInstrumento`)

**addTo*** is used from the parent towards the child which means

"**Add the parent as a foreign_key reference to the child**", which means

`classeInstrumento.addToInstrumentos(new Instrumento())`

will work and not the former approach you use.

Answer (score 0):

```
instrumentoInstance = new Instrumento().addToClasseInstrumento(classeInstrumento)

classeInstrumento = classeInstrumentoService.getClasseInstrumento("value")

classeInstrumento .addToInstrumentos(instrumentoInstance)
```

this is only possible or you should change you belongs to vice versal in case if you have missed domain requirements.